# Active Directory GUID

Tags: active-directory, guid

I need a unique GUID that never changes per user in active directory... I see objectguid, msExchMailboxGUID, attributesecurityguid but not sure which one to use. I think objectguid is what I want but I'm not positive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`objectGUID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221017.aspx) sounds reasonable.